# Are there normalized equivalents to Skewness and Kurtosis?

Tags: skewness, kurtosis

What would be the normalized equivalent to Skewness that would have the same unit as the data? Similarly, what would be the normalized equivalent to Kurtosis? Ideally, these functions should be linear with respect to the data, meaning that if all observations were to be multiplied by a factor `n`, the resulting normalized skewness and kurtosis would be multiplied by the same factor `n`. The benefit of having such normalized equivalents would be to be able to overlay them on top of a standard box-and-whisker plot.

Comment: What a fun question!

Comment: I'm not sure how enlightening it would be to illustrate these on graphs. The reason we illustrate standard deviations is that they give a natural measure of the dispersion of the data (if it's normally distributed): 65% of the observations lie inside the interval. I don't think there are such natural visual interpretations for the third and fourth moments.

Comment: What are you trying to show about your data? If it's a certain qualitative behavior of the distribution, might a [violin plot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Violin_plot) be preferable? But yes, anyway, it's a fun question.

Comment: One can get a sense of skewness and kurtosis by looking at a histogram showing the distribution of one's dataset, but it will give a very subjective perception of these measures. I would like to depict them on two linear scales, one for skewness parallel to the axis of the box-and-whisker plot, the other orthogonal to it. This could be depicted as a separate box overlaid on top of the primary box. The taller that box, the more skewed the data is. The wider, the more pointy (high kurtosis).

Comment: And thanks for the link to the violon plot. It's really clever.

Comment: @Ben Kuhn: 65% for a normal; should be 68%. (Naturally, you can add arbitrarily more significant figures.)

Comment: "Normalized" across mathematics and science has a whole bundle of different meanings, but it often means scaled, unit-free, standardized or corrected, If anything here is normalized, it is the unit-free shape measures called skewness and kurtosis, not what you seek instead.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Skewness measures are deliberately *unitless*.

The usual moment-skewness is a standardized third moment, $E[(\frac{X-\mu}{\sigma})^3]$.

If you center but don't standardize, you have $\mu_3=E[(X-\mu)^3]$... which is plainly then in *cubed units*.

If you wanted something in the same units as $X$, you'd have to take the cube-root, in the same way that we take square root of variance and get something in the same units of the original data. (However - beware, because many packages won't take cube roots of negative numbers, you might have to compute it as: $\quad\text{sign}(X-\mu)\times |E(X-\mu)^3|^{1/3}\:$.)

I'm not sure how useful that will be.

For some other skewness measures, like the two Pearson skewness measures, you just multiply by $\sigma$.

For sample skewness measures where $\sigma$ and $\mu$ are generally not known, as with sample skewness, you'd typically replace them by their own sample estimates.

Kurtosis follows the same pattern - for moment kurtosis, you'd need to take fourth roots of the *unstandardized* fourth moment to get something that scaled with the data.

For some of the other measures of kurtosis, they would only need to be multiplied by $\sigma$.

Answer (score 10):

Skewness and kurtosis are shape characteristics. So, if I tell you that the thing, a ball, is *round* it shouldn't matter what is a radius of the thing. It can be a small ball or a big *ball*. On the other hand, when I say *small* ball or a *large* cube I'm referring to the size of the object, not the shape.

In this regard, the standard deviation is the size of the distribution, that's why skewness and kurtosis are **normalized** by size. You could also say that standard deviation belongs to mechanics, and skewness and kurtosis to geometry. Therefore, no, we don't need to have them in units of measure of the variable. Size and shape are separate. A large and a small ball are equally *round*, i.e. size doesn't matter in this case :)

Answer (score 1):

Denoting vectors which is distributed in region $R$, let's assume the zeroth and the first moment is already normalized. The second moment is calculated with $M_2 = \int_R {x x^T} |dx|$, so if we can find diagonalization $M_2 = P\Lambda^2 P^T$, then we will be able to define $$x'=\Lambda^{-1} P^Tx$$
so that $M_2$ is normalized:

$$M'_{2ij} = \int_R {(\Lambda^{-1}P^T x)(\Lambda^{-1} P^T x)^T} |dx|$$
$$= \Lambda^{-1} P^T (\int_R { xx^T |dx|}) P \Lambda^{-1} $$
$$= \Lambda^{-1} P^T P \Lambda^2 P^T P \Lambda^{-1} = I$$

Geometrical meaning of the second moment is "orientation", which is justified by the fact that diagonalization normalizes the second moment. When skewness is calculated under this normalization, it is called **Mardia's skewness**.